# Pygame menu вопрос про выбор сложность

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-menu

Подскажите пожалуйста, что мне нужно прописать в функцию `set_difficulty`, чтобы при выборе сложности (например, Hard) значение некоторой переменной `difficult` принимало значение 1, а при других уровнях сложности — другие значения. Не смог найти примеров и пояснений в интернете

```
def set_difficulty(value, difficulty):
    # Do the job here !
    pass

def start_the_game():
    # Do the job here !
    pass

menu = pygame_menu.Menu(300, 400, 'Welcome',
                       theme=pygame_menu.themes.THEME_BLUE)

menu.add_text_input('Name :', default='John Doe')
menu.add_selector('Difficulty :', [('Hard', 1), ('Easy', 2)], onchange=set_difficulty)
menu.add_button('Play', start_the_game)
menu.add_button('Quit', pygame_menu.events.EXIT)
```

Comment: Надо не искать примеры и пояснения в интернете, а читать книжки и думать самостоятельно. В данном случае поможет ключевое слово if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ — это записать выбранное значение в глобальную переменную:

```
difficult = 1

def set_difficulty(value, difficulty):
    global difficult
    difficult = difficulty
```

Если хочется обойтись без глобальных переменных, можно вместо функции в качестве параметра `onchange` передать метод какого-нибудь класса, в котором будет храниться информация о настройках.

---

Update:
По поводу того, как управлять присваиваемым значением.

Когда вы задаёте selector, вы передаёте в него список пар (название, значение). Так что изменив значение в соответствующей паре можно управлять тем, что будет передано в функцию `onchange`:

```
menu.add_selector('Difficulty :', [
        ('Hard', 1), 
        ('Easy', 2)
#                ^ эти значения и передаются в функцию.
    ], onchange=set_difficulty)
```

Comment: Я не могу понять,как нам конкретно задать,что если мы выбираем "Hard",то в переменной difficult будет присваиваться конкретно 1,easy  - 2 и тд.Можете пожалуйста объяснить

Comment: Не надо учить плохому, а именно использованию global.

Comment: Можно взять пример выбора сложности из самой библиотеки: https://github.com/ppizarror/pygame-menu/blob/2e7c423e43249b44130bcec770c09662dd7dbd50/pygame_menu/examples/game_selector.py

Comment: @niciki Добавил пояснение про присваемые значения

Comment: @Эникейщик Думаю, в конкретно этом случае важнее дать человеку возможность получить результат, чем загрузить теорией о том, как это сделать правильно и почему global — это плохо. Кстати, в самой библиотеке из комментария ниже тоже используется глобальная переменная, хоть и без явного global.

Comment: Никто не о говорит о загрузке теорией. Можно просто сразу показать нормальный вариант, без уоюпоминания всяких глобал.